# XMLHttpRequest pending in Chrome but is fine on IE

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

The data that I want to get is from API that is only return XML format.
When using IE the request is send and I get beck a response and all is fine. But when I try to use Chrome same request is in pending.

Also I have try the same code to call some open API on internet for testing that return .JSON and the same code is working on Chrome. So what am I doing wrong ?

```
var req = null;
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            alert("Hi")
        }
    };
    req.open("GET", "LINK" ,false);
    req.send(null);
```

Comment: *"...same request is in pending..."* What do you mean by that? What specifically are you seeing?

Comment: Side note: `false` as the third parameter to `open` is a bad idea, and will likely stop being respected at some point. It creates a **synchronous** request, which blocks the UI of the page (at best) or browser (at worst) until the network operation is complete. It's never a good idea. Instead, leave it off to use the default `true` for an asynchronous request.

Comment: I just tried the code above in Chrome and it worked just fine.

Comment: As a side note, I am always amazed to see how many people still use the old school syntax `new XMLHttpRequest()` and all the literature that goes with it (`onreadystatechange`, `req.readyState`, `req.open("GET")`, `req.send` etc.) instead of [fetch](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/). We see questions using `XMLHttpRequest()` all day long

Comment: For asynchnonous request use true instead of false.   Furthermore try `((req.status >= 200 && req.status < 300) || req.status == 304)`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder by (same request is in pending) I mean when is called the same URL from Chrome and IE.  Also as I mention if I try to call lets say from Chrome this API "https://api.publicapis.org/entries" that return JSON the code is working properly I get 200 status in Network(Developer console). The only time is  not working  on Chrome is when I call a API that is returning XML and I get pending status in Network(Developer console).

Comment: @JeremyThille - Well, [if they want IE support](https://caniuse.com/fetch)... :-)

Comment: @m4rtin - There should be an error in devtools, check the console tab. Are you by any chance doing this from a file you open from your file system, not something loaded via `http:`/`https:`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, come on, Microsoft themselves are now officially killing IE, after years encouraging people to switch to Edge. The era of "We still need to support IE" is over (at last!)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is not from file is from (http://127.0.0.1:81/api/XXXX )and i dont get any errors in console...  This is a WebApp that is calling a local server (WebEngine) that is returning that XML formatted data.  Also I have tried to call the API using fetch and still is the same problem.

Comment: @JeremyThille I know but this application that I am using is only working on IE. And the programmers that are working are not interested to make it compatible with Chrome and we are stack with IE. So now I am trying to develop some first version that will work on Chrome.

Comment: Well, good luck to these programmers in 2022 when IE will officially be dead :/ It reminds me of a Flash developer back in 2013, when flash's death was clearly announced, and this guy wouldn't switch to anything else and only wanted to remain a Flash developer. I told him, you're going to sink with the boat, he didn't listen and sank with the boat.

Comment: @JeremyThille - Hey, **I'm** not the one saying they need IE support. :-) No project I'm in charge of supports IE anymore, not even the enterprise app for big companies (the last holdout).